# Find XML element based on attributes

Tags: c#, linq

Assume I have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" mergefield="blah">

    <filter blah="rrr"></filter>
    <filter blah="qqq"></filter>
    <filter blah="www"></filter>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Each time `targetElement` should be assigned if its corresponding attribute name is found in `sourceElement`

```
namespace Test

{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var path = (@"PATHFORXML");
        XElement target = XElement.Load(path);
        XElement source = XElement.Load(path);

        foreach (var sourceElement in source.Elements())
        {


            XElement targetElement = target.Elements().SingleOrDefault(
                    t =>
                        String.Equals(
                            (string)t.Attribute(GetMergeAttr(target)),
                            (string)sourceElement.Attribute(GetMergeAttr(source)),
                            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                  );
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GetMergeAttr(XElement element)
    {
        return (string)element.Attribute("mergefield");
    }
}
```

}

**PROBLEM**

Now I have a situation where `mergefield` can be either `"blah"` or `"blahblah"`. So I want above code to work same way for this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" mergefield="blah,blahblah">

    <filter blah="rrr"></filter>
    <filter blahblah="qqq"></filter>
    <filter blahblah="www"></filter>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Aka, either of `mergefields` should work

**My attempts** are those. `GetMergeAttr` should become this:

```
private static string[] GetMergeAttr(XElement element)
        {
            var f = ((string)element.Attribute("mergefield")).Split(',');
            return f;
        }
```

and I can't finish query part

```
XElement targetElement = target.Elements().SingleOrDefault(
                        t =>
                            String.Equals(
                                (string)t.Attribute(GetMergeAttr(target).SingleOrDefault(u=> ?????????)),
                                (string)sourceElement.Attribute(GetMergeAttr(source).SingleOrDefault(u => ?????????))
                                )
                      );
```

This works, but what if I have more than 3 mergefield values **(I need to update this query to accept any number of mergefields, not just 2)**:

```
            XElement targetElement = target.Elements().SingleOrDefault(
                    t =>
                        String.Equals(
                            (string)t.Attribute(GetMergeAttr(target).Last())?? (string)t.Attribute(GetMergeAttr(target).First()),
                            (string)sourceElement.Attribute(GetMergeAttr(source).Last()) ?? (string)sourceElement.Attribute(GetMergeAttr(source).First())
                            )
                  );
```

Comment: Are the mergefields always being divided with a comma? If yes you could use String.Split https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8 and return both fields.

Comment: @zanseb Yep, they are divided by comma. I can't come up with proper LINQ query for that, it keeps throwing exceptions

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ , it might be me. I reorganized question to make it runnable

Comment: So is your difficulty "extracting the values to look for" or "checking against multiple values"? Those are separable tasks.

Comment: @JonSkeet , I can extract mergefields value and even split them, but I can't check against multiple values. Split returns an array, and i'm not really sure how to make use of that

Comment: Hint: you could either do it in the query, or you could add an extra `foreach` loop. (Separately, it's not clear why you're loading the same XElement twice... `target` and `source` are loaded from the same file...)

Comment: @JonSkeet , I'm trying to reproduce my issue in simplest way possible, that's why i'm using same file. I see how I can do that in extra foreach loop, but doing it within query itself seems to me more "beautiful". I'll end up using other forach if i can't figure out the other way. And I'll have to call foreach twice, since attributes might not be always identical (source vs target)

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please edit the question and more explanation and example about the `target`, `source` and the expected output.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide examples of target,source and expected output ...especially with case where there is multiple matches

Comment: So, example is provided in PROBLEM part. Each targetElement should be equal to sourceElement in that xml.

Comment: @EricKlaus The question was more on scenario where  both Source and Target mergeFields equals "blah,blahblah" with both set of xml containing both blah and blahblah.  What happens next ?

Comment: I just need to assign targetElement if there is something in sourceElement with same attr and attr value. Ex, in foreach loop first sourceElement is `<filter blah="rrr"></filter>`, I look whether it has  attr in mergefield (either blah or blahblah) and then compare it against all targetElements(in SingleOrDefault), to see whether any of targets has same attr (where attr should exist in target's mergefield (either blah or blahblah in our case)) and attr value and then grab and assign that element to targetlement. There isn't any duplicates of form `attr="attrvalue"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update based on comments.

I assume following is what you require

```
XElement target = XElement.Parse(txml);
XElement source = XElement.Parse(sxml);
var targetMergeAttrs = GetMergeAttr(target);
var sourceMergeAttrs = GetMergeAttr(source);

foreach (var sourceElement in source.Elements())
{
        foreach(var mergeField in sourceMergeAttrs)
        {

            if(sourceElement.Attributes().Any(x=>x.Name.LocalName.Equals(mergeField)) &&
            target.Elements()
                  .Any(x=>x.Attributes()
                                      .Where(c=>c.Name.LocalName == mergeField 
                                      && targetMergeAttrs.Contains(mergeField)
                                      && c.Value == (string)sourceElement.Attribute(mergeField)).Any()
                                      ))
            {
                XElement targetElement = target.Elements()
                  .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Attributes()
                                      .Where(c=>c.Name.LocalName == mergeField 
                                      && targetMergeAttrs.Contains(mergeField)
                                      && c.Value == (string)sourceElement.Attribute(mergeField)).Any()
                                      );
                // Do work with targetElement 
                break;
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: My example above returns "sequence contains more than one matching element exception"

Comment: Please have a look at my last code part in the post. That works if I have 2 mergefields. I want it to work for any number of mergefields. Order doesn't matter

Comment: @EricKlaus Looks like there was more one match. What should be done in such scenario ?

Comment: there shouldn't be more than one match. it is either blah or blahblah

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve but does this code behave as expected?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = (@"PATH");
            XElement target = XElement.Load(path);
            XElement source = XElement.Load(path);
            var mergefields = GetMergeAttr(target);

            foreach (var sourceElement in source.Elements())
            {
                var targetElements = from mergefield in mergefields
                                     select target.Elements().SingleOrDefault(t => 
                                         {
                                             if (t.Attribute(mergefield) == null || sourceElement.Attribute(mergefield) == null)
                                             {
                                                 return false;
                                             }

                                             return String.Equals(
                                             t.Attribute(mergefield).Value,
                                             sourceElement.Attribute(mergefield).Value,
                                             StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                                         }
                                     );
                foreach (var element in targetElements)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(element);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string[] GetMergeAttr(XElement element)
        {
            string mergefield = (string)element.Attribute("mergefield");
            return mergefield.Split(',');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This almost works, but target element here might have null value too. Is it possible to make targetElement XElement instead of var?\

Comment: It depends. If you can be sure that there is always a match you can invoke `Single` instead of `SingleOrDefault`. Otherwise you could cast the `IEnumerable<XMLElement>` to a List.